# Delay camera preview for augmented reality

Tags: android, camera, augmented-reality

I'm developing an android application that uses the rear camera in combination with generated 3D graphics (augmented reality).

I see that the 3D graphics sometimes appears later than the camera image displayed when the device is moving. To make it more realistic, I would like to delay the preview from the camera so the camera frame is the same as the 3D rendered surface.

Is it possible to delay the preview from the camera? And if so, how can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

You can hide the native preview SurfaceView, and draw the augmented video frames "above" it.

Comment: I'm not familiar how to display the frames from an onPreviewFrame() callback into a new SurfaceView.

Comment: I did not suggest showing the video frames in a SurfaceView; at least, I have never tried. What I did try, was to create an OpenGL surface and render the video frames by updating a texture.

Comment: yes, I did that in the past, but I thought there would be limitations (like you needed a square texture?) and I though it would be overkill to use OpenGL for just displaying a single image of a video stream.

Comment: No, you don't need a square texture, it's only OpenGL logical coordinates for texture that are expressed in [0..1] floating numbers. No, OpenGL is not an overkill - it is actually the underlying technology for all hardware acceleration anyway.